# Curl PUT data is not received

Tags: asp.net, curl

I'm trying to parse a file sent through http CURL PUT method. I'm using generic handler for parsing the file. I have created a generic handler for getting posted file. Following is the ASP.Net Code:

I'm not able to receive any file or contents. Do I have any problem in my code? Also following is the CURL script that is being used for sending file:

```
public class Test : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            //VALIDATE FILES IN REQUEST
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    //HANDLE EACH FILE IN THE REQUEST
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile item in context.Request.Files)
                    {
                        item.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp/" + item.FileName));
                        context.Response.Write("FILE UPLOADED");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //NO FILES IN REQUEST TO HANDLE
                    context.Response.Write("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //NO FILES IN REQUEST TO HANDLE
                context.Response.Write("NO FILE(S) SENT");
            }

           context.Response.Write(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //result = "205";
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
function putRequest($url, $data)
{
    $putData = tmpfile();
    fwrite($putData, $data);
    fseek($putData, 0);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $putData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
    fclose($putData);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $headers['http_code'];
}

$url= " http://api.domain.com/upload/ ";
$data = "21.2,1000,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
echo "Starting the put request<br />";
$ret = putRequest($url,$data);
echo "Returned code: $ret<br />";
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use CURL?

Comment: @Kangkan Thank you for you prompt reply. This is the standard code as per specification of my client. CURL code is being used by electronic device which sense data and post to the server. I have created a generic handler to retrieve to posted file. The server is responding to the CURL code as 200 (http response code). I guess it is communicating to my web server but I did not receive any file. Even not any object.